# Passing Struct array elements as parameters to a function in Go language

Tags: arrays, function, go, struct, parameters

I have defined a function `possiblemoves()`, that takes in two integers as parameters, but later I want this function to make a call to all the elements in `Struct array` recursively
I didn't put the terminating condition yet, I will do it once I finish it

Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

/*type node struct{
     prev node
     current node
      Next [64] int
}*/
type rowcol struct {
    row int
    col int
}

func main() {
    possiblemoves(1, 5)
}
func possiblemoves(row int, col int) {
    var c [8]rowcol
    var a [16]int

    a[0] = row + 1
    a[1] = col - 2
    a[2] = row - 1
    a[3] = col + 2
    a[4] = row + 1
    a[5] = col + 2
    a[6] = row - 1
    a[7] = col - 2
    a[8] = row - 2
    a[9] = col + 1
    a[10] = row - 2
    a[11] = col - 1
    a[12] = row + 2
    a[13] = col - 1
    a[14] = row + 2
    a[15] = col + 1

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] <= 0 {
            a[i] = 0
        }
        fmt.Println(a[i])
    }

    c[0] = rowcol{a[0], a[1]}
    c[1] = rowcol{a[2], a[3]}
    c[2] = rowcol{a[4], a[5]}
    c[3] = rowcol{a[6], a[7]}
    c[4] = rowcol{a[8], a[9]}
    c[5] = rowcol{a[10], a[11]}
    c[6] = rowcol{a[12], a[13]}
    c[7] = rowcol{a[14], a[15]}

    for j := 0; j < len(c); j++ {
        {
            possiblemoves(c[j])
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do

```golang
type rowcol struct {
    row int
    col int
}

func possiblemoves(rc []rowcol) {}

func main() {
    rc := []rowcol{
        rowcol{1, 2},
        rowcol{3, 4},
    }
    possiblemoves(rc)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/dQ1edTJNhq

`[]rowcol` is a slice of `rowcol` structs. Then you use `rc[1].row` and `rc[1].col` to access these struct fields.